# A state mutation was detected between dispatches while creating new widget-Reactjs ,Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Getting error while creating widget list

if i click on widget list for the first time i am able to create the widget       (widget 1).

if i create another widget to it i am getting an error(A state mutation).

if i create another widget , i am able to create widget with out error(widget 3 )

**Error:A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path ``. This may cause incorrect behavior.**

code

```
addWidget = (widgetType) => {
let newWidget = {};
switch (widgetType) {
  case 'venn':
    newWidget = {
      widgetName: `widget ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
      widgetType: 'venn',
      leftTarget: '',
      rightTarget: '',
      leftTargetValue: 0,
      rightTargetValue: 0,
      position: { row: 0, col: 0 },
    };
    break;
default:
    newWidget = {
      widgetName: `Default ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
      widgetType: 'venn',
      leftTarget: '',
      rightTarget: '',
    };
    break;
}
this.setState(prevState => ({
  widgetsList: [...this.state.widgetsList, newWidget],
  isHidden: !prevState.isHidden,
  widgetCount: this.state.widgetCount + 1,
}), () => this.props.storyboardActions.addWidget(newWidget, this.props.selectedBoard.boardId));  
};
```

Reducer

```
case types.ADD_NEW_WIDGET: {
  const newBoardList = state.boardList.map((item) => {
    if (item.boardId === action.selectedBoardId) {
      return {
        ...item,
        modifiedAt: Date.now(),
        widgetList: [...(item.widgetList || []), { widgetId: uuid(), ...action.newWidget }],
      };
    }
    return item;
  });
  return { ...state, boardList: [...newBoardList] };
}
```

Action

```
export const addWidget = (newWidget, selectedBoardId) => ({
type: types.ADD_NEW_WIDGET,
payload: { 
widget: newWidget,
boardId: selectedBoardId,
},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:** Bugs in action creator*

Try using action.payload to pass all of your data. You've currently got bugs with your property names, and you're calling the action creator with the params in the wrong order:

```js
// Action Creator
export const addWidget = (newWidget, selectedBoardId) => ({  // <-- Param order
  type: types.ADD_NEW_WIDGET,
  payload: {  // <-- Use payload object
    boardId: selectedBoardId,  // <-- These key names
    widget: newWidget,
  }
});


// Reducer
case types.ADD_NEW_WIDGET: {
  const { boardId, widget } = action.payload;  // <-- Get the data out
  const newBoardList = state.boardList.map(item => {
    if (item.boardId === boardId) {
      const currentWidgetList = item.widgetList || [];
      const newWidgetList = [
        ...currentWidgetList,
        {
          widgetId: uuid(),
          ...widget
        }
      ];

      return {
        ...item,
        modifiedAt: Date.now(),
        widgetList: newWidgetList
      };
    }

    return item;
  });
  return { ...state, boardList: newBoardList };
}
```

---

Can I see your `storyboardActions.addWidget` actionCreator?

I have an idea as to what could be going wrong. The spread operator is a shallow clone, so you aren't guaranteed to be immutable. (Look up [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep) for options.)

I'm not positive what is mutating, though. My best idea with the code you've posted is the `widgetName`, because it's relying on `this.state.widgetCount` for a unique name, but the `setState` method is async, so there's technically a chance for it to go awry (I think.)

I've refactored your code a little. I didn't change much, so I'm not counting on this fixing the problem. But separating the bits out like this will give you opportunities to toss in console.logs to hopefully catch where the mutation is happening.

Let me know if this does anything differently:

```js
getNewWidget = type => {
  switch (widgetType) {
    case "venn":
      return {
        widgetName: `widget ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
        widgetType: "venn",
        leftTarget: "",
        rightTarget: "",
        leftTargetValue: 0,
        rightTargetValue: 0,
        position: { row: 0, col: 0 }
      };
    default:
      return {
        widgetName: `Default ${this.state.widgetCount}`,
        widgetType: "venn",
        leftTarget: "",
        rightTarget: ""
      };
  }
};

addWidget = widgetType => {
  const newWidget = this.getNewWidget(widgetType);
  this.setState(
    {
      widgetsList: [...this.state.widgetsList, newWidget],
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden,
      widgetCount: this.state.widgetCount + 1
    },
    () =>
      this.props.storyboardActions.addWidget(
        newWidget,
        this.props.selectedBoard.boardId
      )
  );
};
```

*Reducer*

```js
case types.ADD_NEW_WIDGET: {
  const newBoardList = state.boardList.map(item => {
    if (item.boardId === action.selectedBoardId) {
      const currentWidgetList = item.widgetList || [];
      const newWidgetList = [
        ...currentWidgetList,
        {
          widgetId: uuid(),
          ...action.newWidget
        }
      ];

      return {
        ...item,
        modifiedAt: Date.now(),
        widgetList: newWidgetList
      };
    }

    return item;
  });
  return { ...state, boardList: newBoardList };
}
```

Comment: component data will be same right if i am not wrong, only action and the reducer has changed

Comment: You need to dispatch the `updateWidget` action in your component, and check the `UPDATE_WIDGET` type on your reducer. Get the names lined up, and the parameter order.

Comment: const { boardId, widget } = action.payload;  boardId is undefined

Comment: Look in your component where you're calling it. `this.props.storyboardActions.updateWidget(
        newWidget,
        this.props.selectedBoard.boardId
      )`.  `this.props.selectedBoard.boardId` needs to be defined.

Comment: facing same issue still

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171714/discussion-between-jmr-and-reed-dunkle).

Comment: No change in the output

Answer (score 0):

One common error which caused this error for me was, when I was cloning into state from props.

```
getFields(props) {
  return ((props.resources.fields && [...props.resources.fields]) || []).map(
    field => {
      field.checked = false;
      return field;
    }
  );
}

this.setState({ fields: getFields(props) });
```

In the above example `fields` was an array of object. And instead of doing a deep copy, i did a shallow copy with `[...props.resources.fields]`.

Doing a deep copy would solve this issue. So, for my case i did one more level of shallow copy as follows:

```
getFields(props) {
  return ((props.resources.fields && [...props.resources.fields]) || []).map(
    item => {
      const field = { ...item };
      field.checked = false;
      return field;
    }
  );
}
```